# Error en proyecto Ionic

Tags: ionic

Al hacer click sobre mi proyecto de angular me nanda una serie de errores similares a este y no entiendo porque, la computadora es nueva y recientemente instale lo siguiente.

- Node
- Angular
- Ionic
- Typescript

Todo va bien cuando creo un proyecto desde cero pero cuando descargo alguno que tiene una version 0.0.2 menor o algo similar da error y en la anterior computadora que tenia no pasaba tal cosa al hacer el mismo proceso.

**ERRORES**
[image: Error de app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No nos indicas si has regenerado los node_modules o no, parece el problema.

En la ruta del proyecto, sugiero eliminar/mover el contenido del directorio node_modules y posteriormente ejecutar el comando: `npm install` en la raíz del proyecto.

Comment: eso hice y no funciona, ese es el error que aparece al hacer el npm i al ejecutarlo en raiz